# CodeIgniter ActiveRecord Query

Tags: codeigniter

I have the following code:

```
$this->db->from('addresses');
$this->db->where('user_id', $this->session->userdata('user.id'));
$this->db->like('country',    $pSearch); 
$this->db->or_like('state',   $pSearch); 
$this->db->or_like('city',    $pSearch); 
$this->db->or_like('zip',    $pSearch);
```

which generates the following SQL

```
SELECT *
FROM (`addresses`)
WHERE `user_id` = '1'
AND  `country`  LIKE '%d%'
OR  `state`  LIKE '%d%'
OR  `city`  LIKE '%d%'
OR  `zip`  LIKE '%d%'
ORDER BY `country` asc
LIMIT 15
```

Is there a way to make it generate it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`addresses`)
WHERE `user_id` = '1'
AND  (`country`  LIKE '%d%'
OR  `state`  LIKE '%d%'
OR  `city`  LIKE '%d%'
OR  `zip`  LIKE '%d%')
ORDER BY `country` asc
LIMIT 15
```

As i whant to get only the records for user_id = 1 and not for all users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems to be a bug/limitation in CI ActiveRecord. You could try [Ignited Query](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/IgnitedRecord/IgnitedQuery), which has the ability to handle nested `WHERE` clauses, and probably can handle the nested `WHERE/LIKE` the way you like.

[Check out this thread also for more info.](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/99235/)

Comment: I ended up creating the SQL query myself and using db->query();